# Object properties for an indeterminate number of levels

Tags: php, oop, orm, kohana

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036547/variable-variables-pointing-to-arrays-or-nested-objects) but (literally) takes it to another level, or levels.

Background: I am using the [Kohana PHP framework](http://docs.kohanaphp.com) and, specifically, the [ORM library](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm).

Basically, when you loop through DB results with it, you can access the field values as properties of an object. Any joined tables can be accessed in a hierarchical manner. For example:

```
$users = ORM::factory('user')->with('city')->with('city:country')->find_all();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo "<p>{$user->name} ({$user->city->name}, {$user->city->country->name})</p>";
}
```

will output:

> User 1 (City 1, Country 1)
>
> User 2 (City 2, Country 1)
>
> User 3 (City 2, Country 1)
>
> User 4 (City 3, Country 2)
>
> User 5 (City 4, Country 2)

etc.

Now, my question is: is there a way to access the hierarchical properties of an object for any number of levels. Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
$users = ORM::factory('user')->with('city')->with('city:country')->find_all();
$var2 = 'name';
$var2 = 'city->name';
$var3 = 'city->country->name';
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo "<p>" . $user->{$var1} . "(" . $user->{$var2} . ", " . $user->{$var3} . ")</p>";
}
```

Is this possible in some simple way that I am missing?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$users = ORM::factory('user')->with('city')->with('city:country')->find_all();
$var1 = 'name';
$var2 = 'city.name';
$var3 = 'city.country.name';
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user = $user->as_array();
    echo "<p>" . Arr::path($user, $var1)  . "(" . Arr::path($user, $var2) . ", " . Arr::path($user, $var3) . ")</p>";
}
```

To understand what `Arr:path` does (taken from Kohana's documentation):

```
// Get the value of $array['foo']['bar']
$value = Arr::path($array, 'foo.bar');
```

EDIT:

The above solution is for Kohana v3. 
For Kohana 2.3.4, see the third post on [this page](http://forum.kohanaphp.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=4261).

Comment: Sorry I should have specified I'm using Kohana 2.3.4 - this function appears to be Kohana 3 only.

That said, it is a good solution and one I would definitely use if I were using Kohana 3.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've cracked this.

I've written a function like so:

```
public static function get_attribute($object, $level)
{
    $level = explode('->', $level);
    if (count($level) == 1) {
        return $object->{$level[0]};
    } else {
        $object = $object->{$level[0]};
        unset($level[0]);
        return self::get_attribute($object, implode('->', $level));
    }
}
```

God bless recursion.

Comment: And if anyone has a better answer than this, I'd be more than happy to accept it.