# Variable variable, building an array variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I want to be able to pass a string ("['parent_array']['child_array']") to a function that then pulls this string and "my_array" to the front of it and then creates a variable variable.

Then inside the function i do print_r($$string) and nothing comes out. See the code below for a better explanation.

```
// DOES NOT WORK
$string1 = "my_array['parent_array']['child_array']";
print_r($$string1); //prints nothing.

// WORKS
$string2 = "test";
$test = "This will be printed!";
print_r($$string2); //prints "This will be printed!

// WORKS
print_r($my_array['parent_array']['child_array']);
```

Comment: May I ask why are you building the variables this way? I could bet a large sum of money for there being a more reasonable approach than *(shudder)* variable variables.

Comment: and / or eval, I bet one of the answers later would actually recommend to use eval

Comment: @andreas No sooner said than done...

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036547/variable-variables-pointing-to-arrays-or-nested-objects

Comment: You seem to be **asking for a bugfix of a patch from solution to a problem**. That not the way to go. Instead you should describe the problem, show how you tried to sole it and ask for better solution or changes for the existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable variables are an ugly, ugly hack.

Use [eval](http://au.php.net/eval).

Example:

```
$expr = "\$my_array['parent_array']['child_array']";
$val = 'not assigned';
eval("\$val = $expr;");
print_r($val);
```

But please follow their warnings about the danger of evaling user-supplied code.

**Updated:** with example

Comment: Can I get a example how this would look like?

Comment: Both are ugly hacks IMHO. Almost always there is a better solution. The real question to OP would be: why do you think you need it?

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa look here: http://pastebin.com/bBS4iiMC

I want to be able to pass a variable to the function that replaces "line29. $arrXml['Assignments']['Assignment']"

Comment: If `eval()` is the answer, you are asking the wrong question (or have an extreme lisp).

Comment: @halliewuud And you can't do `$arrXml[ $var1 ][ $var2 ]` because...?

Comment: @halliewuud you know you have a function in a function right? If you call the 'mother function' multiple times you end up with a `fatal error`, because you are trying to redeclare a function.

Comment: @halliewuud I still don't see why you need either `eval()` or variable variables. See Juhana's comment.

Comment: You might need to explain yourself better. How does the naming/scoping of an 'inner' function relate to your original question?