# PHP variables variable not displaying if passed as an array or object

Tags: php, arrays, variables, object

This works with simple variables. But it shows empty result with complex variables. AM I MISSING SOMETHING HERE? or is there anyother way around. Thanks.

```
#1. This works with simple variables.
$object = "fruit";
$fruit = "banana";

echo $$object;   // <------------ WORKS :outputs "banana".
echo "\n";
echo ${"fruit"}; // <------------ This outputs "banana".


#2. With complex structure it doesn't. am I missing something here?
echo "\n";
$result = array("node"=> (object)array("id"=>10, "home"=>"earth", ), "count"=>10, "and_so_on"=>true, );
#var_dump($result);

$path = "result['node']->id";
echo "\n";
echo $$path; // <---------- This outputs to blank. Should output "10".
```

Comment: I guess that it will search for some variable named `result['node']->id`, of course that variable does not exist (not wanting to say it's invalid), hence echoing empty.

Comment: so, how would I achieve the result I need?

Comment: your requirement is very close to what `eval()` function can do. However it's still not what you want. I don't think you can achieve such a dynamic parsing (and also I'm not sure why you want to do something like that). If we can parse that string to evaluate the expression to some ***assignable*** result, it would make the `eval()` become redundant (or less powerful).

Comment: +1 for eval().  See my answer below

Comment: There is an answer to a similar question. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036547/variable-variables-pointing-to-arrays-or-nested-objects

Comment: Please consider eval as a last option. See this [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php) for why eval is (mostly) evil.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly using variable variables, but if you want to use a variable as the var name, eval should work

`$path = "result['node']->id";
eval("echo $".$path.";");`

Answer (score 0):

From [php.net's page on variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

> A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable.

The issue is that `result['node']->id` is not a variable. `result` is the variable. If you turn on error reporting for PHP notices you will see the following in your output:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: result['node']->id ...

This can be solved as follows:

```
$path = "result";
echo "\n";
echo ${$path}['node']->id;
```

The curly braces around `$path` are required.

> In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an
>   ambiguity problem. That is, if you write `$$a[1]` then the parser needs
>   to know if you meant to use `$a[1]` as a variable, or if you wanted `$$a`
>   as the variable and then the `[1]` index from that variable. The syntax
>   for resolving this ambiguity is: `${$a[1]}` for the first case and
>   `${$a}[1]` for the second.

If not present the statement is equivalent to

```
${$path['node']->id}
```

which will result in the following output:

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'node' in /var/www/html/variable.php on line 18
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: r in /var/www/html/variable.php on line 18
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/variable.php on line 18
```