# php: accessing array dynamically using a string variable

Tags: php, arrays, eval

Its like this

I have a variable that has an array index in it, for e.g.

```
$var = 'testVar["abc"][0]';
```

or

```
$var = 'testVar["xyz"][0]["abc"]';
```

or it could be anything at run time.

Now when I try to access this by using this php code:

```
echo $$var;
```

or

```
echo ${$var};
```

I get a warning saying Illegal offset at line ...

but if I use this code, it works

```
eval('echo $'.$var);
```

I do not want to use eval(). Is there any other way?

EDIT:

The variable $testVar is an array build up on runtime and it could have multi-dimensional array built dynamically. Its format is not fixed and only the script knows by the use of certain variables that what the array could be.

for e.g. at any point, the array might have an index `$["xyz"][0]["abc"]` which I want to access dynamically.

My php version is 5.1

Comment: Could you `var_dump` that `$testVar` variable?

Comment: which version of php are you using? what's exactly the warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), what you are trying to accomplish is not possible:

> In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an ambiguity problem. That is, if you write `$$a[1]` then the parser needs to know if you meant to use `$a[1]` as a variable, or if you wanted `$$a` as the variable and then the `[1]` index from that variable. The syntax for resolving this ambiguity is: `${$a[1]}` for the first case and `${$a}[1]` for the second.

In your case, `$$var` tries to read a variable with the name `testVar["xyz"][0]["abc"]`, and not indexing an array. You could dereference that array like this:

```
$a = "testVar";
echo ${$a}["xyz"][0]["abc"];
```

Comment: Further solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466815/php-variable-variables-with-array-key and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036547/variable-variables-pointing-to-arrays-or-nested-objects

Comment: Actually I cannot use the approach you mentioned in the code above i.e. `$a = "testVar";
echo ${$a}["xyz"][0]["abc"];` because the actual part that is unknown at runtime is `["xyz"][0]["abc"]`, it could be anything at runtime

Comment: @ImranAhmed I advise you to reconsider your software design. If you rely on variable variables like this, I think you should design it differently. If that is not possible (legacy code, time limits, etc) you are stuck with `eval`.